# During a local merge, can I reset file file to merge start state (with conflicts)

Tags: git, merge

I'm in the middle of a big merge, and I accidently saved a file. I guess I could do a messy `git stash`, `git pop` and re-resolve the conflicts. But is there an easy way to "replay the diffing" on a single file?

Initial:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Mr President
=======
Madam President
>>>>>>> 3fdad6a888b68e2c538dfcd52f4594fea7b9e4d4
```

Saved (Accident):

```
Mr Madam
```

Is there a simple way to return to initial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `git checkout` with `--merge` option:

```
git checkout -m single_file.txt
```

Quoting [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout--m):

> ```
> -m
> --merge
> ```
>
> [...]
>   When checking out paths from the index, this option lets you recreate
>   the conflicted merge in the specified paths.